# Simple JavaScript math not making sense

Tags: javascript, math

I feel like I'm a novice again. I thought I was long past these problems. below is a simple script with two function neither of which work. What am I missing. Any help appreciated.

```js
function calculator() {
  var bee = document.getElementById("beerPerc").value;
  var win = document.getElementById("winePerc").value;
  var liq = 100 - (bee + win);
  document.getElementById("liquorPerc").value = liq;
}

function calculator2() {
  document.getElementById("liquorPerc").value = parseInt(100 - (document.getElementById("beerPerc").value + document.getElementById("winePerc").value))
}
```

```html
<div id="calcArea">
  <div>
    <input type="number" id="beerPerc" value="50" onkeyup="calculator2()"> &nbsp; % of Beer Drinkers<br>
    <input type="number" id="winePerc" value="30" onkeyup="calculator2()"> &nbsp; % of Wine Drinkers<br>
    <input type="number" id="liquorPerc" onkeyup="calculator2()"> &nbsp; % of Liquor Drinkers<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean? Please tell us what  do you expect from the script and how does it actually behave.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Case is significant. If you declare the variable `bee`, you can't read it with `Bee`.
2. `.value` is always a string. You need to convert the strings to numbers:

   ```
   var bee = Number(document.getElementById("beerPerc").value);
   ```

If you don't do this, `+` will perform string concatenation, not addition.

You don't need to call `parseInt()` on the result of a numeric calculation, that's always a number.

```
function calculator2() {
    document.getElementById("liquorPerc").value = 100 - (parseInt(document.getElementById("beerPerc").value, 10) + parseInt(document.getElementById("winePerc").value, 10)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the revisit of the rules. much appreciated